# Simple JS function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project and I have this function imported from a simple .js file. Im calling these functions on a state inside a React Native component, and on a button to update that state with what the function returns.

For some reason, it returns undefined instead of the true/false returns Im expecting to receive.

```
export const requestLocalizationPermissions = () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    return true
  }

  PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    {
      title:
        'Accept this',
      buttonNeutral: '',
      buttonNegative: 'Cancelar',
      buttonPositive: 'OK',
    },
  )
    .then(res => {
      if (res === 'granted') {
        PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            title:
              'Accept this',
            buttonNeutral: '',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancelar',
            buttonPositive: 'OK',
          },
        )
          .then(res => {
            if (res === 'granted') {
              console.log('sucess')
              return true
            } else if (res === 'never_ask_again') {
              Alert.alert(
                'Error',
                texts.unblock_localization,
                [
                  {
                    text: 'OK',
                    onPress: () => console.log('Login > Alert hidden'),
                  },
                ],
                { cancelable: false },
              )

              return false
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            return false
          })
      } else if (res === 'never_ask_again') {
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          texts.unblock_localization,
          [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('Login > Alert hidden') }],
          { cancelable: false },
        )

        return false
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return false
    })
}
```

I do get printed on the console the success message, but I do receive undefined when I log the function called.

Comment: There are many places where you are not returning anything... for example... if res is not equal to `granted` or equal to `never_ask_again`... you are not returning anything (obviously, I don't know all the possible values... but that could be the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some feedbacks that I would suggestion for you:

Wrap this function around an `async` function one, something like this:

```js
const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
        message:
          "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
          "so you can take awesome pictures.",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("You can use the camera");
    } else {
      console.log("Camera permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};
```

This block of code is from the React Native doc.  https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid

And this function `PermissionsAndroid.request` returns a promise, maybe this is the reason you were receiving this `undefined`.

You need to return the result of it as well. Therefore:

```js
export const requestLocalizationPermissions = () => {
 ...
 return PermissionsAndroid.request(...)
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return after then. like that=>

```
return axios
                .get(`${SERVER_API}/getChannel/${channel}`)
                .then((resp) => {
                  return resp.data;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that `PermissionsAndroid.request` is a promise and your function call will not wait for it response to return to the code, you can change this for something like this:

```
export const requestLocalizationPermissions = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    return true
  }

  try {
    const permission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Accept this',
        buttonNeutral: '',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancelar',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      }
    )

    if (permission === 'granted') {
      const permissionRes = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Accept this',
          buttonNeutral: '',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancelar',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        }
      )

      if (permissionRes === 'granted') {
        console.log('sucess')
        return true
      } else if (permissionRes === 'never_ask_again') {
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          texts.unblock_localization,
          [
            {
              text: 'OK',
              onPress: () => console.log('Login > Alert hidden'),
            },
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        )

        return false
      }
    } else if (permission === 'never_ask_again') {
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        texts.unblock_localization,
        [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('Login > Alert hidden') }],
        { cancelable: false }
      )

      return false
    } else {
      return false
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return false
  }
}
```

Just remember that your function is now a promise and you will need to await for the response.